# Multiple Javascript pop-up windows

Tags: javascript, popup

Is it possible to in a situation like this;

```
<li><a href="javascript:productPop('includes/products/test.php','8 mil');">asadfasdf</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:productPop('includes/products/test.php','15 mil');">asdfasdf</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:productPop('includes/products/test.php','hello');">asdfasdf</a></li>
```

to have the windows open in a cascade? So that the user can compare windows side by side.

**Other relevant code**

```
var newwindow;
function productPop(url)
{
    newwindow=window.open(url,name,'width=560,height=340,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or please suggest a better way to accomplish the same thing

Comment: A website that opens 3 popups when I click on a link ? If you manage to do that, you'll never have me stay, nor come back, on your site...

Comment: I know it's not the best solution but the client specifically asked for this feature and it's one link opens one window. You click on product 1 it opens the window for product one and then you click on product 2 and it opens the window for product 2. That way you can compare them side by side. Each window will also have close buttons. If there is a better solution please tell me, but this was the only one I know of.

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible although getting them to line up consistently will be challenging.

As Joel suggested, it's not desirable in terms of usability.

For side-by-side comparisons, have you considered a single page that allows them to add and remove items for comparison?

One implementation I'm familiar with is at http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/findacar.htm - but there are probably better ways of achieving this goal.

EDIT: As requested, I think your code is almost there.  Might add the name parameter - if the name doesn't change it won't open a new instance of a window with each call (I'm assuming you fixed this already based on your HTML).

```
var newwindow;
function productPop(url, name)
{    
   newwindow=window.open(url,name,'width=560,height=340,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0');  
   if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

Comment: I have thought of many different ways. But not only does the client specifically want windows that pop up but he also doesn't want to pay for the time it would take to develop that. They don't have to line up next to each other, I just want both windows to stay in front of the browser. As it is now, when you open a new window the previous window gets sent to the far back

Comment: Sometimes users ask for things because they don't know of a better way.  Maybe they don't like the postback effect that the figure is mandatory when adding new items?  AJAX would fix that.  Of course, you can't do much about them not wanting to pay for something better... :)

Comment: Yes, I know everything that everyone is lecturing me on. I tried to convince him of another way, but if this is what he wants, this is what he wants. I appreciate the feedback but could you please tell me the "technically possible" way to do this. Clearly this isn't the best client, so I'd just like to give him what he wants and have it over with. Please and thank you.

Comment: I have appended `time` with name of window, and it opens as many as required to me :) this works, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that, set the locations of the popups with javascript. May I ask why you are using popups? There are many other, less annoying ways of displaying information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the location thing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hatdrawn: I reckon Dan means the window positions. Each subsequent window is open relative to the previous window position.